# how to create tablespace with set initial size in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have, in oracle, this following sql command to create a tablespace with initial size:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tb1 DATAFILE 'file.f' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

I didn't find the same sql command for Postgresql.

According to my research there is't a possibility to set this field in postgres.

I need to set it because it increases the performance of my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: you can't

The way Oracle stores data is completely different to the way Postgres does it. Postgres doesn't store everything in a single (tablespace) file the way Oracle does it.

A tablespace is not a file as in Oracle it's just a directory where Postgres stores the files for tables located in that tablespace. And because it's just a directory "pointer", there is no initial size you can specify.